# Как сократить большие числа до к, М и т.д.?

Tags: php

Нужно сократить большие числа до `к`, `М` и т.д.

Например:

```
1000000 = 1М
500000 = 500к
```

По сути вот готовый вариант реализации, но непойму как сделать чтобы сократить числа со знаком "минус"?
Например:

```
-1000000 = -1М
-500000 = -500к
```

Прошу помощи.

```
function number_name( $number )
{
  if( !is_numeric( $number  ) ) {
    return $number;
  }
  $digits = ceil( log10( $number ) ) -4 ; //число знаков минус 4
  $mult = pow( 10, $digits ) ; //множитель для оставления первых 4 знаков
  $number = round( $number / $mult ) ; //оставили 4 знака
  while( ( $number > 1000 ) || ( $digits % 3 != 0 ) ) {
    $number /= 10 ;
    $digits += 1 ;
  }
  $names = array( 0  => "",
                  3  => " к",
                  6  => " М",
                  9  => " Г",
                  12 => " Т"); //число нулей => название
  return $number.$names[ $digits ] ;
}
```

Comment: `как сделать чтобы сократить числа со знаком "минус"?` - бери модуль числа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал чуть проще (без возведения в степень и логарифмов):

```
function number_name($number)
{
    $count = array("", "k", "M", "G", "T");

    $i = 0;
    while (abs($number) > 1000) {
        $number /= 1000;
        $i++;
    }

    return $number.$count[$i];
}

echo number_name(5)."\n";
echo number_name(5000)."\n";
echo number_name(-5000)."\n";
echo number_name(5000000)."\n";
echo number_name(5000000000)."\n";
echo number_name(5000000000000);
```

Вывод:

```
5
5k
-5k
5M
5G
5T
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function number_name( $number )
{
    if( !is_numeric( $number  ) ) {
        return $number;
    }

    $isNegative = ($number < 0); //определение отрицательного числа
    if($isNegative) $number *= -1; //приведение к абсолютному

    $digits = ceil( log10( $number ) ) -4 ; //число знаков минус 4
    $mult = pow( 10, $digits ) ; //множитель для оставления первых 4 знаков
    $number = round( $number / $mult ) ; //оставили 4 знака
    while( ( $number > 1000 ) || ( $digits % 3 != 0 ) ) {
        $number /= 10 ;
        $digits += 1 ;
    }
    $names = array( 0  => "",
        3  => " к",
        6  => " М",
        9  => " Г",
        12 => " Т"); //число нулей => название
    if($isNegative) $number *= -1; //возвращение к отрицательному, если нужно
    return $number.$names[ $digits ] ;
}
```

Добавил только обработку отрицательных, остальное оставил Ваше.